# Azure file share mapped drive with multiple usernames

Tags: azure, fileshare, mapped-drive

I have created an azure file share and I was able to create mapped drive on my system , but I need to share different folders to different users

currently I have only one username which is the storage name provided by azure

Answer (score 0):

By default mapping of an Azure File Share happens using SMB protocol that makes use of your storage account name/key.

However, you can also enable Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS) authentication over SMB for Azure Files which will let you grant granular NTFS permissions on folders and files inside a share to users.

Please visit this link for detailed instructions on how you can accomplish that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-enable.